# 2D interval scheduling problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation, scheduling, intervals

Suppose I give you $n$ axis-aligned rectangles with a specified width, height, and x-position (of the left edge) $\{(w_i, h_i, x_i) \mid i \in \{0, \ldots, n - 1\}\}$, as well as a bound $(y_\mathrm{min}, y_\mathrm{max})$ on the valid y-positions. These rectangles must have integer-valued coordinates for their vertices. Is there an efficient (e.g.: $O(n^3)$) approximation algorithm that gives a sequence $\{y_0, \ldots, y_{n - 1}\}$ of y-positions such that the number of overlaps between any two rectangles (i.e.: edges in the overlap graph) is minimized (and hopefully zero)?

Note that if $y_\mathrm{max} = 10$ and $h_k = 3$, then $y_k = 9$ would be invalid, since the top edge would be at $12$ which is more than $10$.

Comment: Just to be sure, if we have $w_i$ and $x_i$ we can safely assume we know for each rectangle its projection into the $x$ axis to be $[x_i, x_i + w_i]$. So we only need to choose for every rectangle the $y_i$ coordinate of its lower edge. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It reminds me to a very difficult problem which can be seen as a 1D version of this problem. Check it [here](https://icpc.kattis.com/problems/scenery). This was the hardest problem in the ICPC World Final competition (so you can assume it was very hard). Check the [editorial (problem H)](https://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/problems/icpc-solutions2017.pdf). Your problem can be reduced to this problem (for the zero overlapping case). They quote this paper  “Scheduling Unit-time Tasks With Arbitrary Release Times and Deadlines” by
Garey, Johnson, Simons, and Tarjan (SICOMP, 1981).

Comment: Ohh, I missed something important from your problem, $[y_{min}, y_{max}]$ is fixed for all rectangles. Disregard previous message, I'll leave it in case the quoted paper helps you somehow, but it is not the same problem.

Comment: I think in graph theoretic terms this is a variant of $T$-coloring problem in interval graphs, and maybe related to the frequency assignment problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the offline dynamic storage allocation problem. Check out the papers cited by https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539703423941 for a good review of the literature.